# Import csv file with decimal values to mySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I'am trying to import the following data with this statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/path/Desktop/decitable.csv'
INTO TABLE  technical_center.decitable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

csv-Data:

```
intRow;deciRow
4;2.43
```

The sql data fields are formatted as INT(11) and DECIMAL(11).
After executing the import statement I receive the values 4 and 2.
Where is the Problem in mySQL workbench with this sql statement?

Comment: Your decimal column does not allow for any digits after the decimal point. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: If you want decimal *places* you need to *define* decimal places, with e.g. `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

Comment: Worked for my problem. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in CSV or Import procedure, please change DECIMAL(10) to DECIMAL(10,2) if you need two digit on decimal

Hope this helps

Comment: But not for money values. And FLOAT is not a better solution than DOUBLE for other values unless space is a major concern and you know you have a very limited range of values.

Comment: _“I would personally recommend FLOAT as better solution to keep numbers with or without decimals”_ – that really depends on what that data is actually meant to represent. If it was for example money values, then using float would be grave error. (If you don’t know why, then I suggest you do some research on that.)

Comment: I did not say for what scenario, the purpose was to store any number without rounding

Comment: BS. What you actually said, and I quote, was 'I would personally recommend FLOAT as better solution to keep numbers with or without decimals'.

Comment: Can someone tell me why I still get the warning: 1265 truncated for column '...' at Row 1 ?

Comment: Try to remove column name or LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' with this LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: Work's perfect. Thank's a lot!